# how to make pandas dataframe start iterating at a different row while iterating?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for example if you had a dataframe containing numbers from 1-10, and if it finds the value 5 while iterating, you want it to go back or forward a few rows to do perform some operation that has to be done row by row, in this case to keep it simple just skip the next row to resume the iteration, how can you do that?

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
df.columns=['number']

start=0
for index, row in df.iloc[start:].iterrows():
    print(index, row['number'])
    if row['number']==5:
        start=index+2
```

with this i just get:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
```

but i wanted it to give me:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish because you do not really need a loop to do this in pandas? For example if you want to do a cumulative sum but skip every occurrence of 5 . . . `df['cumsum'] = df.where(df['number'] != 5)['number'].cumsum().ffill()`

Comment: im trying to do something else with some finance data, has nothing little to do with math functions, but more about imitating intuition. i was given the data in the form of a dataframe, but things i'm checking can only be found in hindsight by looking at the data sequentially row by row, and once i find a specific thing i want to go back to a certain row to start performing the same operation again

Comment: There should be a hot-line for anyone who starts working with `pandas` and thinks he has something that "has to be done row by row" to show him how it can be done better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your comments on your question it looks like that your question is just an example to find out a way to do what you actually want, which looks like the XY problem. Although I am pretty sure what you need can be done in the pandas way, which is vectorized and fast if you want a generic way to loop and skip rows, go back or whatever based on a condition you can loop over the dataframe (going to be slow but ok)

```py
i = 0
while True:
    if i >= len(df):
        break
    row = df.iloc[i]
    if condition1:
        i += 10
    elif condition2:
        i + = 5
    elif condition3:
        i = max(0, i - 10)
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: thanks, using while loop seems to be a simple, direct solution to the question in the title. i understand efficiency is important, but sometimes thats not the priority but rather just trying to find an answer, and the most intuitive solution would be the best starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Find values equals to 5 and shift the mask then invert the mask and keep all other rows:

```
df = df[~df['number'].eq(5).shift(fill_value=False)]
```

```
>>> df
   number
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
6       7
7       8
8       9
9      10
```

Comment: You probably want to filter on the number column and not the index `df[(df['number'] != 5).shift().bfill()]`

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to me that it is the index which is filtered?

Comment: I am pretty sure. It seems to me the OP wants to "go back or forward a few rows" when they "[find] the value 5" in the number column (`row['number']==5`). I would not assume the actual data is ordered `range(1,11)` so we cannot not assume that the row after 5 will always be index 5. Also if the index is an object you run into issues as well . . . `pd.DataFrame(range(1,11), columns=['number'], index=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))`

Comment: @It_is_Chris,  In that sense it is bit unclear to me what exactly  OP wants,  OP must introduce some reproducible data. Based what is expected, it right.

Comment: @KarnKumar there are many ways to get an "expected output" without it being the correct way to do so.

Comment: @It_is_Chris, that's the question of right data and right information out of which expected results needed.

Comment: @It_is_Chris. I think you right now. Can you check my new answer, please?

Comment: @Corralien yes, I believe that is closer to what the OP is looking for +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
df.columns=['number']

start=0
for index, row in df.iloc[start:].iterrows():
    if index==5:
        # you can do your operation here
        continue
    else:
        print(index, row['number'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need you can also use a simple for loop with enumerate() method:

```
for index, row in enumerate(df.number):
    if index != 5:
        print(index, row)
    else:
        continue
```